# Creating Snake on a website with an account system

Tags: web

For my coursework, I am creating a basic Snake game. However, this will be hosted on a website and will have a database back-end for account creation and storage of high scores.

I am currently planning to use:
HTML/CSS/JavaScript for the website
JavaScript to actually create the game
Flask/SQLite for the account database

Is there anything else I may need to accomplish this? The website can be hosted at my school. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can create the game with everything you've mentioned.

You may need a domain name, unless your school is supplying one.

`HTMl/CSS` - layout of the website / game

`Javascript` - Logic of the game`

`Database / SQLlite` - Store highscores

`School's Web Server` - Host the website.